# Dynamically add "items" (ASCXs) to a repeater on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to build an ASPX page where I have a this repeater to pull out these 5 questions items. Each item has a user control (with radio buttons) which need to be displayed. 
Now what I want to achieve is:

1. At first just the first user control is displayed. The user selects a certain radio-button from this user-control.
2. Only and only when a user selects a radio button, we have to decide whether the 2nd item is to be displayed or not - based on the user selection.
3. This should continue for the list of 5 items.

Is there a way to make the repeater wait for the remaining items to load until the user interacts with the user control of the current item? If so, how?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.  I don't want any code for now but just a path/direction/pointer to follow.

Thanks!

Comment: You say repeater, but the questions have user controls? Are they custom? Repeaters are good for repeating, data-driven templates. Is that what you have, or do you just have some custom controls that need to appear in sequence?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: There are different user controls defined for different types of questions. Every question item has a user control and these user-controls need to be displayed for the user to interact. And yes, they do have to appear in sequence.
Would repeater be the best option to go forward here?

Comment: Unless you can tell me there is something *repeatable* about the questions, I wouldn't recommend a repeater. So far, it sounds like the only pattern they follow is that one can be displayed after/depending on the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably render all the controls server-side, and then use javascript to show and hide them.
This will provide a responsive solution, and simplify your code.

**Edit**
Assuming you don't mind that the client can see your underpants.

Comment: The anti-simplification aspect is now you have 2 independent pieces of code to maintain in different languages, and the questions, answers, and logic are all publicly visible for the world to see with a simple right-click.